# TextBox show variable type - not content

Tags: .net, string, c++-cli

I try put the folder name in textbox so i'm used this code:

```
private: System::Void textBox1_DragEnter(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DragEventArgs^  e) {
             if (e->Data->GetDataPresent(DataFormats::FileDrop))
             {
                 e->Effect = DragDropEffects::Copy;
             }
         }
private: System::Void textBox1_DragDrop(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DragEventArgs^  e) {
             if (e->Data->GetDataPresent(DataFormats::FileDrop))
             {
                 textBox1->Text = Convert::ToString(e->Data->GetData(DataFormats::FileDrop));
             }
         }
```

It's working (0 errors) but when i put folder into textbox, textbox show me not path but: `System.String[]`

I'm using: C++, .NET, Visual Studio 2010

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e->Data->GetData(DataFormats::FileDrop)
```

Is returning a `string[]` (an array of strings), not a single `string`. When you try to convert this to string using `Convert::ToString`, it just uses the default `Object.ToString()` behavior of showing the type name. What else would you expect it to do? There is no default notion of aggregating an array of strings into a single one.

You should use the object returned by `GetData()`, and convert it to a string yourself. If you expect a single item, test for that, grab the first item, and you have your string.

If you want to support many items, you can use `string.Join()` for example and specify a delimiter.

You should use this to get access to the dropped files data:

```
array<System::String^>^ items = (array<System::String^>^)e->Data->GetData(DataFormats::FileDrop);
```

From there you can decide how to convert `items` to a string.

Comment: Hmm ... so that's my problem. 
I have no idea how i can convert System::Object^ to System::String^ without Convert class. Can you show me any example or ideas how to do it?

Comment: Edited my answer to give a start for you.